# How do I embed a url parameter in the path using slash instead of a question mark?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typically you write url parameters like this:

```
some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page?item=0c3af753
```

I've also seen some web pages format the parameter like this:

```
some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page/0c3af753
```

And sometimes there is something else after it like this:

```
some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page/0c3af753/edit
```

Is this possible in React? If I try to format the path like this I get a `No routes matched location` warning in console.

I tried to just put the parameter in the path directly like this:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const item = "0c3af753";
navigate({pathname: `/page/${item}`})
```

Comment: i do not have much knowledge of frontend, but on backend if ? is used we can access items by using req.query and if you send page/${item} on backend we have to set route like /page/:item and we can access by using req.params.items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your route to accept a param or `Dynamic Segment` as react-router calls it. This is explained in the [document here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments).

> If a path segment starts with : then it becomes a "dynamic segment". When the route matches the URL, the dynamic segment will be parsed from the URL and provided as params to other router APIs.

To implement this, define a `Route` in your router like this, check how the `path` prop is defined.

```js
// this path will match URLs like /some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page/0c3af753
<Route
  path="/some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page/:item"
  element={<ItemPage />}
/>;

// this path will match URLs like /some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page/0c3af753/edit
<Route
  path="/some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page/:item/edit"
  element={<ItemEditPage />}
/>;
```

And you can call use `navigate` from your code snippet to pass the param like this:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
const item = "0c3af753";
navigate(`/some-nonexistent-webpage.com/page/${item}`);
```

And you can access the param on the page using `useParams`:

```js
function ItemPage() {
  let params = useParams();
  console.log(params.item); // "0c3af753"
}
```